# Javascript not responding to on click event [Laravel 5.5]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I want a pop-up screen with a contact form when clicking on a button. My Javascript function is not reacting on a on-click..

I import the JS-file in the main html page where I import cantact.blade

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/provider/contact-provider.js') }}"></script>
```

Loading the Javascript files works, the program also goes into the init function when loading. But never in the on-click function..

contact.blade.php:

```
        <div class="o-grid">
            <div class="o-grid__col u-7/12@lg u-border--contact">
                <td><a href="#" class="c-btn c-btn--red c-btn--small contact-form-result .contact-form-result-modal"
                       data-location=""id="contact-provider-button"
                       data-detail-route="{{ route('vendor.contact', ['profile' => $profile],true) }}"
                       data-modal-open="contact-provider-form">@lang('profile.btnContact')</a></td>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT (contact-provider.js):

```
var ExtendedForm = ExtendedForm || {};

/**
 * Show search form modal with detailed info
 * @type {{init}}
 */
ExtendedForm.showSearchDetail = (function ($) {

  var _$container;
  var _$modal;

  var _clearAndShow = function () {
    $('.modal-content', _$modal).html('');
    _$modal.css({display: 'block'});
  };

  var _getContent = function (url) {
    $.get(url, function (res) {
      $('.modal-content', _$modal).html(res);
    });
  };

  /**
   * DOM ready inits
   * @private
   */
  var _init = function () {

    _$container = $('.contact-provider-button');
    _$modal = $('#contact-provider-form');

    $(function () {

      // click search result
      _$container.on('click', '.contact-form-result-modal', function (evt) {
        alert("message");
        evt.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).data('detail-route');
        $('body').addClass('u-overflow--hidden u-relative');
        _clearAndShow();
        _getContent(url);
      });

    });

  };

  return {
    init: _init
  }

})(jQuery);

ExtendedForm.showSearchDetail.init();
```

Comment: If the JavaScript is loaded at the *top* of the HTML, the container element will not yet be part of the DOM so the `.on()` jQuery call won't do anything.

Comment: @Pointy it only need to do something when clicking on the button in the contact.blade.php

Comment: See what happens if you move the initialization of `_$container` and `_$modal` to the **inside** of the "ready" handler function.

Comment: @Pointy, I removed the initialization into the init function, but that didn't do anything (also deleted my cache history)

Comment: Not into the `_init` function, into the function you pass to `$()` — the anonymous function where you call `_$container.on()`.

Comment: Also giving an element a class name with `.` in it (".contact-form-result-modal") is almost certainly a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are referencing a class instead of an id. Change

```
_$container = $('.contact-provider-button');
```

to

```
_$container = $('#contact-provider-button');
```

Additionally, as @Pointy mentions in the comments, it is better to only reference DOM elements in the ready handler, otherwise you might get an exception or unexpected behaviour.

Comment: This is true, but additionally that initialization should be moved into the "ready" handler.

Comment: @Pointy why? :)

Comment: Because if it is not, and the `<a>` element is not yet part of the DOM, *the code will not work.* Why would you not want to at least *try* that?

Comment: So, if the button is not rendered, it will not work? that's ok, though?

Comment: You also need to fix the class name in the HTML — the class name should not start with "."